# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}z^{n(n+1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I'm interested in finding the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}z^{n(n+1)}$. My first step was to rewrite this series into the standard power series form like this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}z^{n(n+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_nz^n  $$
where $b_k = \begin{cases} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} & \text{ if } k =n(n+1) \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{N} \\ 0 &\text{ else} \end{cases} $

We now would like to appeal to the root test. We look at $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}} $. Taking natural logs and using L'Hopitals quickly tells us that this limit is 1.

So is the radius of convergence 1? This just doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Just find $\limsup_{n\to\infty} (|a_{n(n+1)}|^{1/n(n+1)})$ because term that is zero have no contribution to limit superior of $|a_n|^{1/n}.$ Now $\limsup|{a_{n(n+1)}}^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}|=(\frac{1}{n})^{1/n(n+1)}=1$ as $1\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n(n+1)}\leq n^{1/n}.$

Comment: Yeah, I tried this actually and I'm not keen on computing lim sups. Any tips? I was able to compute the limit of that expression but I'm not sure if it will equal the lim sup.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts I edited for more comfortable.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more question. You have $a_{n(n+1)}$ but then you write $\frac{1}{n}$. Shouldn't it be $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$?

Comment: @NicholasRoberts $a_{n(n+1)}$ is co efficient of $x^{n(n+1}. $

Answer (score 1):

Both your approach and your answer are correct.  If $\vert z \vert \gt 1$, then the terms of the series don't approach $0$ so it can't possibly converge.  If $\vert z \vert \lt 1$, then the series is smaller (in absolute value) than $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{z^n} n}.$$